# Nightwatch Mocha Reporter without describe-it syntax

Tags: xml, junit, mocha.js, reporting, nightwatch.js

I want to use Mocha reporting without changing the default syntax of Nightwatch because I find it easy as compared to mocha's describe-it syntax? Is it possible? See an example below:

```
module.exports = {
'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
client
  .url('http://www.google.com')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
  .assert.title('Google')
  .assert.visible('input[type=text]')
  .setValue('input[type=text]', 'rembrandt van rijn')
  .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
  .click('button[name=btnG]')
  .pause(1000)
  .assert.containsText('ol#rso li:first-child',
    'Rembrandt - Wikipedia')
  .end();
}
};
```

I want to generate Mocha report for above Nightwatch test.

Comment: Have you tried using the reporter already? What were the results?

Comment: As per documentation, I cannot use Mocha reports without changing the test runner to Mocha and then I will have to change the code styling everywhere which I don't want to do.

Comment: You may have just answered your own question. All joking aside, I think you will either need to look around and see if anyone has built a reporter to do what you are asking or build one yourself.